# Regexp for public IPV4 excluding local and broadcasted IPs WITH NO LOOKBEHIND

Tags: regex, safari, ipv4

I'm facing the following problem : I need two regexp to validate if an IPV4 and IPV4-cidr is valid.

```
const iPv4 =
    /^(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?<!172.(16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31))(?<!127)(?<!^10)(?<!^0).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?<!192.168)(?<!172.(16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31)).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?<!.255$)$/;
```

And

```
  const iPv4Cidr =
    /^(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?<!172.(16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31))(?<!127)(?<!^10)(?<!^0).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?<!192.168)(?<!172.(16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31)).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?<!.255$)[/](24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|32)$/;
```

My problem is that lookbehind is not supported by Safari , Is there a way to transform those regexp  without using lookbehind ?

Thx

I tried different librairies such as is-ip / ip-regex and is-cidr / cidr-regex  but none of them fits.

It validates local IPs such as

```
const localIPs = [
        '172.16.0.9',
        '172.16.4.1',
        '172.17.1.1',
        '127.0.0.2',
        '10.0.1.5',
        '10.0.0.1',
        '10.155.155.155',
        '10.255.255.254',
        '172.16.0.4',
        '172.16.0.1',
        '172.17.1.1',
        '172.31.254.254',
        '192.168.1.2',
        '192.168.254.0',
      ]
```

or broadcasted IPs such as

```
const broadcastIPs = ['60.123.247.255', '196.168.255.255', '10.255.255.255', '192.168.255.255'];
```

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/hiVopA/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it matchs with 192.168.1.2 and
192.168.254.0 so no

Comment: And what is the expected result?

Comment: it should not match with all the local IPs . 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.254.0 should not match

Comment: Ok, I see, https://regex101.com/r/hiVopA/2 should work. Note that in the original regex, the first `(?<!172.(16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31))` is redundant, the regex will work the same even if it is removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in your regex, the first `(?<!172.(16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31))` lookbehind is redundant as it does not do anything real.

To fix the issue, the lookebehinds need to be converted to lookaheads, and `\b` word boundaries can be used at the end of their patterns to so as to ensure exact number matching.

You can use

```
^(?!127)(?!10\b)(?!0\b)(?!192\.168\b)(?!172\.(16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31)\b)(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(?!255)(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hiVopA/2).